# Output CSS from javascript and then make a callback

Tags: javascript, css

My dilemma is this, i'm going to write a php script that will write CSS to a javascript file. I need this JS file to, when called as a css file, output just the css. I then need to make a get request from the same JS file to an endpoint back on my server. Now my specific questions are: how exactly can i output pure CSS from a JS file. And if i make a get request in the same JS file will this interfere with the outputting of the CSS?

Comment: Why do you *have* to serve CSS from the JavaScript file? If you're writing the CSS to a JS file using PHP, why can't you just serve up the CSS from the PHP file on the server?

Comment: Because i need to store said CSS file on a CDN, but also have it intelligent enough to log when a request is made to it. Hence i need Javascript to output the CSS

Comment: Even if you're using a CDN, why does it have to be the same file? Surely your CDN will allow you to place two files on their network?

Comment: Of course, but how does this help my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Get the css string using `htmlobject.style.cssText`.

If you want to get a stylesheet, use the StyleSheet object. Hints:

StyleSheets (Array-like) object `document.styleSheets`
CSSRule (Array-like) object `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules`
CssText (string) `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText`

Use [`document.styleSheets[0].insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) if you want to add some CSS strings, use `document.createElement("style")` if you need to create a StyleSheet object when the document doesn't have one yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't serve CSS from a JavaScript file. Serve your CSS and JavaScript from two separate locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your JS file output pure CSS by doing something like:

```
document.write("<style>.rule1 { ... }</style>");
```

But, I have to ask, why not have PHP directly output CSS?

Comment: see my comment on the question. Need to put it onto a CDN